# How to make function take in generic vector?

Tags: c++

Very new to C++.

Let's say I have a function `bubblesort()` that takes in a vector. I want it to take in vectors of int, and char*.

How can I make it so the argument parameter is generic?

E.g.

```
void bubblesort(vector<T> a) {

}
```

Where `T` can be any type?

Comment: You just use template

Comment: Any type all in the same function or are you willing to accept a templated function?

Comment: What purpose could there be in sorting a `vector` of `int`s or `char*`s in the same way? Are you really asking how to make it work for both a C array of characters and a vector of ints?

Comment: Note that you could use similar code to sort `int` and `char*` if you only compare the pointer's value, not a potential null-terminated string at the pointer. And even then it is only meaningful if the `char*`s being sorted all point to the same object. That said, I don't se much use in sorting addresses, but I'm certain there are cases where it could be useful.

Comment: Note that you could use similar code to sort `int` and `char*` if you only compare the pointer's value, not a potential null-terminated string at the pointer. And even then it is only meaningful if the `char*`s being sorted all point to the same object. That said, I don't se much use in sorting addresses, but I'm certain there are cases where it could be useful.

Comment: Read the chapter about _templates_ in your C++ book.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a template function:

```
template<typename T>
void bubblesort(std::vector<T>& a) {
    
    }
```

Note that you need to pass `std::vector<T>` by reference (adding `&` token) in order to make sorting results available back in the caller function.

What kind of `T` will this function work for? You did not show the implementation, but typical way would be relying on `operator <` for type `T`. In case of `char*`, would you really want to sort by the address? Probably not, so instead of `std::vector<char*>` you would want `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: May also mention the need to either pass the compare function or to ensure it is set somewhere else and visible within the bubblesort to handle the differing types of `T` submitted.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Note that I mentioned using operator< as the comparison method. Passing a separate comparator is another complication, which I thought would be too much for a beginner.

Comment: That's a good call, but he will run into it one way or the other. At least `std::greater` and `std::less` are fairly generic for basic types `:)`